# Windows Batch Scripting: Open Git Bash in a specific location

Tags: batch-file

Need to open git bash in a specific location as if right clicking on the folder and select "Git Bash Here".

```
start C:\"Program Files"\Git\git-bash.exe
```

What should be added to this line so the bash opens in a specific directory?

Comment: You can do it in a single command. Please open a Command Prompt window, type ```start /?```, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the output. The method should look a littl, lihe this: ```@Start "My Title" /D "W:\orking\Directory" "%ProgramFiles%\Git\git-bash.exe" --Any Arguments```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
@echo off
cd "C:\PATH\TO\YOUR\DIRECTORY"
start "" "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i
```